# Alert if Linux ssh daemon stopped on Azure

Tags: linux, azure, azure-monitoring

Is it possible to send an alert if an OS daemon has stopped/died on a Azure Linux VM ?

For example: I want an alert if the VM's ssh daemon has been stopped or died.

Which areas in Azure do I need to look at to configure this alerting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure an alert when azure Linux VM has ‘stopped’ via using ***‘syslog’ in Azure Log Analytics Workspace***

Also,whenever a Linux machine is stopping, all the information is logged in /var/log/messages file you can try the below step to configure alert

***Go to azure portal** -> **Log Analytics workspace** ->**Agents configuration** ->**syslog** -> **filer type 'daemon'** -> **apply***
[image]

***In your azure portal ->log Analytics workspace -> General -> Logs*** -> close the query workspace **->** **syslog -> under syslog ->SyslogMessage -> use below query ->click ‘Run’**.

Check ‘*SyslogMessage*’ column in the output

[image]

> Syslog | where (Facility == "daemon") | where (SyslogMessage has "xxxxxxx" and SyslogMessage has "stopping") | summarize AggregatedValue= any(SyslogMessage) by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 30s)

*I am able to set the alert, as my VM has not stopped so while running the query, have  created a sample for you*

***To set alert :***

In ***Log Analytics workspace*** -> ***alert*** ->***configure custom log*** ***using this query*** -> set your condition and details to get notified on alert getting triggered.

[image]

For more information in detail Please refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54561462/how-can-i-create-an-alert-in-oms-when-a-linux-service-is-stopped) designed  by ***KrishnaG-MSFT***

Comment: Thank you, would that show an alert if the daemon was killed or died abnormally ? ie not stopped gracefully ?

Comment: Also found its possible to do it this way: ConfigurationChange
| where ConfigChangeType == "Daemons" and SvcName contains "XXXXX" and SvcState!= "Running"